# What's the difference between Factory and ServerFactory/ClientFactory?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm currently reading a book about Twisted and the code examples seem to use both `protocol.Factory` and `protocol.ServerFactory/ClientFactory` arbitrarily. What's the difference and when should each option be used?

Here's an example using `protocol.ServerFactory`:

```
class HTTPEchoFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return HTTPEchoProtocol()
```

However, here they're using protocol.Factory:

```
class RshFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connected_clients = {}

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return RshServer(self, addr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClientFactory` and `ServerFactory` are mostly historical accidents that should eventually be removed.  If you're using [endpoints](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.2.1/core/howto/endpoints.html) (and you should be, any code written with twisted in the last 3 years *should* be) you should just use `Factory` and ignore them.

Comment: I must say that it's really nice having the Twisted founder giving support on stackoverflow. Thanks again!